# Python 2.7 Pandas: How to replace a for-loop?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, pandas, scipy, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe with 2000 rows (one date per row) and 2000 columns (1 second intervals). Each cell represents a temperature reading.

Starting with the 5th row, I need to go back 5 rows and find all the observations where the the 1st column in the row is higher than the 2nd column in the row.

For the 5th row I may find 2 such observations. I then want to do summary stats on the observations and append those summary stats to a list.

Then I go to the 6st row and go back 5 rows and find all the obvs where the  1th column is higher than the 2nd column. I get all obvs, do summary stats on the obvs and append the results to the new dataframe.

So for each row in the dataframe, I want to go back 5 days, get the obvs, get the stats, and append the stats to a dataframe.

The problem is that if I perform this operation on rows 5 -2000, then I will have a for-loop that is 1995 cycles long, and this takes a while.

What is the better or best way to do this?

Here is the code:

```
print huge_dataframe

            sec_1    sec_2   sec_3   sec_4   sec_5
2013_12_27   0.05     0.12    0.06    0.15    0.14
2013_12_28   0.06     0.32    0.56    0.14    0.17
2013_12_29   0.07     0.52    0.36    0.13    0.13
2013_12_30   0.02     0.12    0.16    0.55    0.12
2013_12_31   0.06     0.30    0.06    0.14    0.01
2014_01_01   0.05     0.12    0.06    0.15    0.14
2014_01_02   0.06     0.32    0.56    0.14    0.17
2014_01_03   0.07     0.52    0.36    0.13    0.13
2014_01_04   0.02     0.12    0.16    0.55    0.12
2014_01_05   0.06     0.30    0.06    0.14    0.01


for each row in huge_dataframe.ix[5:]:

    move = row[sec_1] - row[sec_2]
    if   move < 0: move = 'DOWN'
    elif move > 0: move = 'UP'

    relevant_dataframe = huge_dataframe.ix[only the 5 rows preceding the current row]


        if   move == 'UP':
            mask = relevant_dataframe[sec_1 < sec_2]   # creates a boolean dataframe
            observations_df = relevant_dataframe[mask]

        elif move == 'DOWN':
            mask = relevant_dataframe[sec_1 > sec_2]   # creates a boolean dataframe
            observations_df = relevant_dataframe[mask]

        # At this point I have observations_df which is only filled
        # with rows where sec_1 < sec_2 or the opposite, depending on which 
        # row I am in. 

        summary_stats = str(observations_df.describe())
        summary_list.append(summary_stats)               # This is the goal 
                                                         # I want to ultimatly
                                                         # turn the list into a 
                                                         # dataframe
```

Comment: Please make it more clear. Optimally, you would want to provide code. Change 500 for 5, 40 for for, and you can at least show in a simple 10 by 10 data frame (or so) what your data looks like and what expected output (at least parts of it) would be.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write (fake) code that shows in "for loops" what you try to achieve differently.

Comment: I think the `huge_dataframe` in your second `if-else` section should be `relevant_dataframe`, right?

Comment: Yes you are right.  I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code to create the data, I will just sketch the code that I would try to make work. Generally, try to prevent from row-wise operations whenever you can. I first had no clue either, but then I got interested and some research yielded `TimeGrouper`:

```
df = big_dataframe
df['move'] = df['sec_1'] > df['sec2']
def foobarRules(group):
    # keep in mind that in here, you refer not to "relevant_dataframe", but to "group"
    if (group.tail(1).move == True):
        # some logic
    else:
        # some other logic

    return str(group.describe())

grouper = TimeGrouper('5D')
allMyStatistics = df.groupby(grouper).apply(foobarRules)
```

I have honestly no clue how the return works if you return a multi-dimensional dataframe. I know it works well if you return either a row or a column, but if you return a dataframe that contains both rows and columns for every group - I guess pandas is smart enough to compute a panel of all these. Well, you will find out.

Comment: If this works, feel free to update with some working code. I'd be interested to see the result.

Comment: No, this will hardly do. It is not a rolling windows operation. You only get two none overlapping windows: 2013-12-27 and 2014-01-01

Comment: Right. Have a look at `rolling_apply` then. It has the downside that the function it takes apparently is only allowed to return a single value. I'd play around a bit myself, but I'm not at my working station right now.